# How to make a many to many or a foreign key not required in a model for django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

here is my model :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    template = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    self_url = models.ForeignKey('liens.Lien',null=True,blank=True)
    Categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie_Page,null=True,blank=True)
    Liens = models.ManyToManyField('liens.Lien',related_name="Liens sur la page",null=True,blank=True)
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ImagesSite = models.ManyToManyField('presentation.ImageSite',null=True,blank=True)
    Texte_contenu = models.ManyToManyField('presentation.Texte_contenu',null=True,blank=True)
    Note_divers = models.ManyToManyField('notes.Note_divers',null=True,blank=True)  
    MiseEnForme = models.ManyToManyField('presentation.MiseEnForme',null=True,blank=True)
    Menu = models.ManyToManyField('presentation.Menu',null=True,blank=True)
    Avis = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.Avis',null=True,blank=True)
    Regle = models.ManyToManyField('regles.Regle',null=True,blank=True)
    Pack = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.Pack',null=True,blank=True)
    Imageventes = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.ImageVente',null=True,blank=True)
    Film = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.Film',null=True,blank=True)
    ImageFilm = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.ImageFilm',null=True,blank=True)
    ImageActeur = models.ManyToManyField('moteur.ImageActeur',null=True,blank=True)
    generated = models.DateTimeField('date published',blank=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('date modified',blank=True)
    protege = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

and i want that all my field could be blank.
How can i do that ?

I have :

```
pages_page.self_url_id may not be NULL
```

or this field is required so ...

Regards
Bussiere

Comment: so what is exactly the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Set on the relevant fields `null=True` and update your database.

It looks like you've already set null on `self_url`, so the problem is that your database has not been updated with this nullable information. Syncdb will not update your tables!

run `python manage.py reset myapp` **(this will destroy / recreate your table)**

Comment: As a side note, the asker might want to look into Django South database schema migration tool in the future.